# Setting and canceling alarms with AlarmManager (Android)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

This is a post requesting confirmation (or rebuttal) of what I believe to be happening with alarms in Android. This subject occurs with some frequency in blogs and StackOverflow posts, but I have not found a clear explanation of these two points (below).

The code below is intended to set and alarm and then to unset it. It does not work.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(AlarmReceiver.ALERT_GUARD_CHECKIN);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, _id, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now.getTime().getTime(), sender);

    Intent toCancel = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    toCancel.setAction(AlarmReceiver.ALERT_GUARD_CHECKIN);
    PendingIntent pendingToCancel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            _id, toCancel, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    am.cancel(pendingToCancel);
```

It does work if, instead of passing PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT to the first call of PendingIntent.getBroadast(), I pass zero instead. I do not believe this behavior is documented.

The code also does not work if second argument of PendingIntent.getBroadast() (above, _id) are not identical. I do not believe this is documented. In the Android docs the second argument is documented as, "Private request code for the sender (currently not used)."

The question is whether I've properly described this behavior, or if these generalizations are of ephiphenomena.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a `PendingIntent` to `cancel()` that is equivalent to the one you used to register the alarm. This means using the same Intent, flags, and request code. Contrary to what the documentation might lead you to believe, it actually checks the request code value as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that confirmation. That is kind of an important thing to include in the docs!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a receiver for the alarm defined in your Android Manifest?

Comment: Yes, I'm receiving the alarms just fine (or not, if I remove it as I described above).